# Create unified diff text for diff2html in browser

Tags: javascript, difflib, unified-diff, diff2html

Is there a library that produces unified diff from two strings that [diff2html](https://github.com/rtfpessoa/diff2html) can use? I've tried [difflib](http://qiao.github.io/difflib.js) but the output does not seem to fit the requirements that diff2html needs. I need a .js library I can import in the webpage to produce diffs between JSONs.

Tried to play around with the `lineterm` parameter but was not able to get the tool to work. If I use the string in the docs as an example, then it works:

```
--- a/server/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/zsyscall_linux_mipsle.go\n+++ b/server/vendor/golang.org/x/sys/unix/zsyscall_linux_mipsle.go\n@@ -1035,6 +1035,17 @@ func Prctl(option int, arg2 uintptr, arg3 uintptr, arg4 uintptr, arg5 uintptr) (\n \n // THIS FILE IS GENERATED BY THE COMMAND AT THE TOP; DO NOT EDIT\n \n+func Pselect(nfd int, r *FdSet, w *FdSet, e *FdSet, timeout *Timespec, sigmask *Sigset_t) (n int, err error) {\n+\tr0, _, e1 := Syscall6(SYS_PSELECT6, uintptr(nfd), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(r)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(w)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(e)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(timeout)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(sigmask)))\n+\tn = int(r0)\n+\tif e1 != 0 {\n+\t\terr = errnoErr(e1)\n+\t}\n+\treturn\n+}\n+\n+// THIS FILE IS GENERATED BY THE COMMAND AT THE TOP; DO NOT EDIT\n+\n func read(fd int, p []byte) (n int, err error) {\n \tvar _p0 unsafe.Pointer\n \tif len(p) > 0 {\n
```

But couldn't get any output of difflib to produce anything in diff2html.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ended up using [jsdiff](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff).

```
var diff = Diff.createTwoFilesPatch("file", "file", oldText, newText);
```

so that it can then be used with diff2html like this:

```
Diff2Html.getPrettyHtml(diff,
    {inputFormat: 'diff', showFiles: false, matching: 'lines', outputFormat: 'side-by-side'}
);
```